# Angular 8 and order of displaying the components

Tags: angular, components

I have two components that are displayed side by side within home component like so:

```
<app-productList></app-productList>
<app-productGallery></app-productGallery>
```

If I comment out the second line (`<app-productgallery></app-productGallery>`), the `app-productList` is displayed instantly, but if I don't (I need both), the gallery gets displayed first and only after all the images in the gallery are loaded/seen, the `app-productList` gets displayed (meanwhile, the product list is empty). I either want that:

- both components get displayed at the same time OR
- productList gets displayed first

I probably could create a promise or an rxjs subject and tell the app that I want to see the gallery only after product list is displayed and not sooner, but my question is more general - why is this even happening, what principle of execution is this following?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Unfortunately, not at hand. I was just wondering if there are any general ways to do this?

Comment: are you sure that the component load is the slow part and not the server response?

Comment: Yes, if I comment out the gallery, the list is loaded instantly.

Comment: Angular components do not **load**. Please use words and examples properly in your questions so that others can understand your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have both component in your `app.component.html` file like this:

```
<app-product-gallary></app-product-gallary>
<app-product-list><app-product-list>
```

Angular Render component exactly based on their order that appears in the `.html` file. So, simply change their order in your template file by something like this:

```
<app-product-list><app-product-list>
<app-product-gallary></app-product-gallary>
```

However if you provide some code we can help you better here as there isn't code here and it's just my guess.